# How to call the self owned function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am writing the typescript for client side language, I just started to learn typescript a few days ago, but there is one problem driving me crazy. I cannot use the function inside of this class.

This is the typescript:

```
   declare var $: any;
declare var query: any;

class Utilities {

    checkLoginStatus(): void {
          query.sendRequest("POST", "/loginRegister/checkLoginStatus", "", function (data) {
        var loginStatusDiv = $("#login_status");
        loginStatusDiv.html("");
        if (data.status) {
            loginStatusDiv.append($("<span>", { text: "Welcome " + data.user_name, class: "col-8 text-right" }));
            loginStatusDiv.append($("<a>", { href: "#", text: "Logout", id: "logout_link", class: "col-4 text-right" }));
            this.handleLogoutClick();
        } else {
            loginStatusDiv.append($("<a>", { href: "login.html", text: "Login", id: "login_link", class: "col-8 text-right" }));
            loginStatusDiv.append($("<a>", { href: "register.html", text: "Register", id: "register_link", class: "col-4 text-right" }));
        }
    });
    }

    handleLogoutClick(): void {
       //some actions

    }
}

let utilities = new Utilities();
utilities.checkLoginStatus();
```

This is the Javascript:

```
var Utilities = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Utilities() {
    }
    Utilities.prototype.checkLoginStatus = function () {
              query.sendRequest("POST", "/loginRegister/checkLoginStatus", "", function (data) {
        var loginStatusDiv = $("#login_status");
        loginStatusDiv.html("");
        if (data.status) {
            loginStatusDiv.append($("<span>", { text: "Welcome " + data.user_name, "class": "col-8 text-right" }));
            loginStatusDiv.append($("<a>", { href: "#", text: "Logout", id: "logout_link", "class": "col-4 text-right" }));
            this.handleLogoutClick();
        }
        else {
            loginStatusDiv.append($("<a>", { href: "login.html", text: "Login", id: "login_link", "class": "col-8 text-right" }));
            loginStatusDiv.append($("<a>", { href: "register.html", text: "Register", id: "register_link", "class": "col-4 text-right" }));
        }
    });

    };
    Utilities.prototype.handleLogoutClick = function () {

    };
    return Utilities;
}());
var utilities = new Utilities();
utilities.checkLoginStatus();
```

This is query.sendRequest

```
declare var $: any;
namespace query {
    export function sendRequest(method, api, praValue, callback): void {
        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: window.location.origin + api,
            data: { data: praValue },
            success: callback,
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Utilities.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: this.handleLogoutClick is not a function
```

It says this.handleLogoutClick is not a function. I thought the typescript is a java-like language, but I do not know how to call the functions inside of this class.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Your code works (I don't errors and `handleLogoutClick `) my guess us that you are passing `checkLoginStatus` to a jQuery event handler, and then you do get into issues with who `this` is ..

Comment: The code that works: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Aclass%20Utilities%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20checkLoginStatus()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fsome%20actions%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.handleLogoutClick()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20handleLogoutClick()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22AA%22)%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20utilities%20%3D%20new%20Utilities()%3B%0D%0Autilities.checkLoginStatus()%3B

Comment: Hi @Kreedz Zhen .. I'm not sure if you have fixed it but you've got an extra curly bracket `}` in there?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes, I am calling it with a jQuery event handler. Do you know how to fix this error?

Comment: @Morema, Thanks, I removed some code after I paste the original code to make this more clear. It was my mistake, but that was not the reason for that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a way to use this in typescript with jquery

```
handelLoginBtnClick(): void {
        var _this = this;
        $('#login_btn').on('click', function () {
            var input = $('.validate-input .user_input');
            for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                _this[$(input[i]).attr("id")] = $(input[i]).val();
            }
            if ($(this).data("is-login")) {
                query.sendRequest("POST", "/loginRegister/login", JSON.stringify(_this), function (data) {
                    _this.handelFallback(data);
                });
            } else {
                if ($(".sign_up_as")) {
                    _this["sign_up_as"] = $("input[name='sign_up_as']:checked").val();
                }
                query.sendRequest("POST", "/loginRegister/register", JSON.stringify(_this), function (data) {
                    _this.handelFallback(data);
                });
            }
            console.log(userLogin);
        });
    }
```

Declare a variable like 
`var _this = this`, 
before the jQuery code. `_this will represent as this class,`

```
$(this) will be the jQuery object.
```

Correct me please, if I am wrong.